# Merge changes from trunk to branch using subclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, merge, subclipse

I use `SVN` as check-in tool and have installed `Subclipse` plugin in my eclipse.

I have done some changes in trunk. I have to merge my changes(from trunk) to some branch.

I have never done merging of code. I have searched it on google and found little confusing.Can someone please let me know the steps to follow.

Comment: why would you want to merge from the trunk to the branch?
normally, you merge from a branch to the trunk. the other way around doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: yeah..that's right but some change is to be migrated from trunk to branch which was left earlier

Answer (score 6):

Did you install the merge plugin from the Subclipse web site?

The general process is that you want your working copy to contain the branch you want to merge into.  So if you want to merge from trunk to a branch, you should have your branch checked out.

You should do Team > Update so that your working copy is at the latest HEAD revision for your branch.  This will make merge faster and run better.

Then do Team > Merge.  The wizard presents some options depending on whether you want to merge all changes from trunk that are not already in the branch or whether you want to select a specific revision(s).  Normally you want to do the former when possible.

You have to enter the path you want to merge from, so something like /trunk or /ProjectA/trunk or possibly something like /trunk/some.company.projecta etc.

Just make sure the "relative path" matches what you have checked out.

Then just click OK.

Merge is like an intelligent editor for your working copy.  When it is done you have changes in your working copy and those still have to be committed.  Be sure to commit the entire working copy so that the SVN merge tracking information is all committed with the changes.